# how to add connection to sql 2008 mdf file from the vista partition in w 8 visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-express

the original app in vista partition was using the connectionstring like

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=c:\MDF\StringTmp.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

I have migrated the app's project to visual studio 2012 pro still targeting .net 3.5

But I got the failed to login with "myw8pcName\username"

I also tried using add connection wizard in visual studio with windows auth. that failed.

I also tried a sql server  application ID and password used in vista for the mdf file in the add connection wizard for "Use sql server Authentication" that also failed

when can I do?

Comment: I was told I could try settinging a new connection in visual studio and use the connection string from there in the application making sure the user can login the sql express instance and user has full  access to the mdf.
I was also told I could try the sql 2012's localdb feature. I found that worked as long as the user, the system, newtorking service(or the sql group) has full access to the file and path

Comment: the connection string using localdb looks like:
 Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true ;AttachDbFileName=...